# Ajax for dynamic combo box selection in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have two combo-box in single page. Now I want that If I select 1st combo-box option then in 2nd combo-box it automatically shows options related the 1st selected option without page refresh.

**My Models:**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, -> { where(:is_active => true) }
  has_many :stores
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, -> { where(:is_active => true) }
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :companies
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  scope :active, -> { where(:is_active => true) }
end
```

In my **HAML View Form**

```
  .field
    .ui-widget
      = f.label :location
      = select_tag(:location, options_from_collection_for_select(Location.active, :id, :name), :prompt => "Select location")

  .field
    .ui-widget
      = f.label :store
      = f.select :store_id, Store.active.collect { |s| [s.name, s.id] }, :prompt => "Select store"
```

I know it is possible by using Ajax and I had also searched many ajax but it is for php and I can't understand how to use. I have never use Ajax before. Please help me.. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all understand one thing that AJAX is not related to php or rails, Its a javascript function call

now as per your question In my **HAML View Form**

```
.field
.ui-widget
  = f.label :location
  = select_tag(:location, options_from_collection_for_select(Location.active, :id, :name), :prompt => "Select location", onchange: "change_store(this)")

.field
.ui-widget#store_list
  = f.label :store
  = f.select :store_id, Store.active.collect { |s| [s.name, s.id] }, :prompt => "Select store"
```

now in **js file**

```
function change_store(select_tag){
  value1 = $(select_tag).val()
  $.ajax({
    url: "controller_name/mehuod_name",
    data: {data1: value1}
  })
 }
```

Now put route in route.rb file and create method in respective controller to find store list, then you can replace html under "select_lit" using jquery, simple

Hope this is what you are expecting